# How to query records in appear in one table, but not in the other two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have three tables: input, results, errors.

input `table`:

```
'input', 'CREATE TABLE `input` (\n  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),\n  UNIQUE KEY `domain_UNIQUE` (`name`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

The `results` table:

```
'results', 'CREATE TABLE `results` (\n  `name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,\n  `no` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `version` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `ext` longtext,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),\n  UNIQUE KEY `domain_UNIQUE` (`name`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

The `errors` table:

```
'erros', 'CREATE TABLE `erros` (\n  `error` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,\n  `code` longtext,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),\n  UNIQUE KEY `ip_UNIQUE` (`name`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

I want to query the `name` field where exist in the `input` table, but not exists in the `results` and not in the `errors` tables.

I tried constructing the query using `NOT IN`, but it lasts forever and then mysql workbench crashes. Note that the `name` field in the `errors` and `results` tables is always a `name` that exist in the `input`, but with a fixed `xxx` prefix.

Here is my attempt:

select `input`.`name` 
from `myscheme`.`input`,  `myscheme`.`results`, `myscheme`.`erros`
where concat('xxx',`input`.`name`) not in (select `results`.`name` from `myscheme`.`results`) 
and concat('xxx',`input`.`name`) not in (select `erros`.`name` from `myscheme`.`erros`);

Can you please help me query the `name` field where exist in the `input` but not in the `results` and not in the `errors`.

Comment: Please look at your formatted post, read the edit help re code blocks & format & indent your code reasonably. Please act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select i.name
from myschee.input i
where not exists (select 1 from myscheme.results r where r.name = concat('xxx', i.name)) and
      not exists (select 1 from myscheme.errors e where e.name = concat('xxx', i.name));
```

Notes:

- I don't know why you want to concatenate `'xxx'` to the name, but presumably you have a reason.
- The query is only selecting from one table, `inputs`, so that should be the only table in the `FROM` clause.
- I strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN`, because `NOT EXISTS` works (as expected) even when the subquery returns `NULL` values.
- I really don't understand the logic you are attempting in your `WHERE` clause.  This seems like an `AND` condition with comparisons on the two tables.

Comment: Thanks. I do not get why don't you use `name`? What are `i.name`, `r.name`, `e.name`? the field in the table is `name` in all the tables? so what are these? I use long name format that comprises the table name and the field name so no confusion occurs.

Comment: Also I do not get `select 1`? what not `select results.name` and `select errors.name`?

Comment: "Also I do not get select 1? what not select results.name and select errors.name? " @user9371654 `not exists` are "short circuiting" keywords which the best work with boolean values like true (1) or false (0).. That's why Gordon is using `SELECT 1` instead of columns names.. Besides `SELECT 1` can be in thoery faster then `select  column` on this method assuming indexes can be used to filter because off `SELECT 1` no extra table data is readed..